# Auto Increment Field in InfoPath Form Based Off of the Value From the Previous Form Submitted?

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a field called "Bulletin#" in my InfoPath form that increments on submit based off of the OOTB SharePoint column "ID".

The rule on clicking "submit" is to check to see if the field "Bulletin#" is empty; if not set the value to max(ID)+1. I have setup a receive connection to query ID.

I followed the same approach; created a receive connection to query Bulletin# (with the library sorted according to ascending ID, so it would get the last Bulletin# used) and use max(Bulletin#)+1.
But I end up getting this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there a workaround or another approach to it?

Thanks

Comment: What is max(Form#) returning? NaN is "Not A Number"

Comment: @rjcup3 yes max(form#) returns nan, although I have set up the field with a integer data type. But max(ID) returns an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was selecting the field from the insert field wizard, I was selecting from under the query fields. 
When I selected from the data fields it worked just fine.
[image]

Answer (score -1):

max(field) + 1

doesn't always work... if the form is opened in edit mode it increments again.